# Querying mongo documents based off of information from a previous query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongodb with an application collection and a user collection. Documents in the users collection contain the applciation ids that can be used to find the application in the applications collection.

This is an example of a user document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("526a8c30f96538307eafe424"),
    "FirstName" : "test first",
    "LastName" : "test last",
    "Email" : "test@test.com",
    "PasswordHash" : "test",
    "ApplicationIds" : [ 
        "175672351", 
        "439632472"
    ]
}
```

This is an example of an application document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("526a8c66f96538307eafe426"),
    "Id" : "175672351",
    "Name" : "test application",
    "CollectionName" : "test collection name"
}
```

I'm using nodejs to query the database so that I can display ALL of the the users applications. So far, I am able to get the user collection and I can get the application ids from that. But the problem I'm having is that I need to get the applcation name and collectionName from the application collection. I've tried using a for loop to find each application ID. Here is what my code looks like presently:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017/sandstorm";
var users;
var applications;
var db = mongo.connect(connectionString, function(err, db) {
        if(err)
                throw err;
        console.log("connected to database");
        users = db.collection("users");
        applications = db.collection("applications");
});

exports.getUserApplications = function(req, res) {
        var email = req.params.email;
        var pass = req.params.pass;
        var appObject = {
                "Status": 0,
                "DataObject": {
                        "Applications":[]
                },
                "UserFriendlyErrorMessage": "",
                "DeveloperErrorMessage":""
        };
        var appDetail = {
                "Id": "",
                "Name": "",
                "CollectionName": ""
        };

        // set response header
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});

        users.findOne({"Email": email, "PasswordHash": pass}, function(err, doc) {
                if(err)
                        throw err;
                if(doc) {
                        // get application ids from the user data
                        var appString = doc.ApplicationIds;
                        var apps = [];
                        for(var i = 0; i < appString.length; i++) {
                                applications.findOne({"Id": appString[i]}, function(err, appDoc) {
                                        appObject["DataObject"]["Applications"] = appDoc;
                                });

                        }
                        res.end(JSON.stringify(appObject, 0, 4));
                } else {
                        appObject["Status"] = 1;
                        appObject["DataObject"] = null;
                        appObject["UserFriendlyErrorMessage"] = "Login Credentials Incorrect";
                        appObject["DeveloperErrorMessage"] = "ERROR: Incorrect Email or Password";
                        res.end(JSON.stringify(appObject, 0, 4));
                }
        });
};
```

One thing I've noticed is that the applications.findOne query inside the for loop will not carry the data outside of that query. The problem is inside that for loop. Is there a way to query all applciations in the collection for a specific user? I need it to so that I can have a json document like this:

```
{
     "Status" : 0,
     "DataObject" : {
           "Applications" : [{
                 "Id" : "175672351",
                 "Name" : "Test Application One",
                 "CollectionName" : "Test Application One"
            }, {
                 "Id" : "439632472",
                 "Name" : "Test Application Two",
                 "CollectionName" : "Test Application Two"
            }]
      },
      "UserFriendlyErrorMessage" : "",
      "DeveloperErrorMessage" : ""
}
```

I only need the applications associated with the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a library like [`async.map`](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) to fix the *retrieving multiple documents from MongoDB in a loop* issue, but if I may suggest an alternative: use [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) to retrieve all application documents with one query:

```
applications.find({ Id : { $in : appString } }).toArray(function(err, appDocs) {
  // TODO: check for `err`
  appObject["DataObject"]["Applications"] = appDocs;
  res.end(JSON.stringify(appObject, 0, 4));
  // or `res.json(appObject)` if you're using Express
});
```

Comment: I tried $in and it returns this: `{ toArray: [Function],
  each: [Function],
  next: [Function],
  nextObject: [Function],
  setReadPreference: [Function],
  batchSize: [Function],
  count: [Function],
  stream: [Function],
  close: [Function],
  explain: [Function],
  isClosed: [Function],
  rewind: [Function],
  limit: [Function],
  skip: [Function],
  hint: [Function],
  maxTimeMS: [Function],
  sort: [Function],
  fields: [Function] }`

Comment: That's using `console.log(appDoc);`

Comment: @user oops, hang on, I'll edit my answer. You need to call `toArray` to read all the results into a proper array.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. It works now. Also, can I get rid of the `_id`? I know theres something like `_id = false` but I think thats for mongoose.

Comment: never mind the last part about removing the _id, I figured out how to do that, I added `{_id:0}` after `{Id: {$in: appString}}`. Thank you for the help

Comment: @user yes I was going to post that otherwise :)